# Pinging virtual host results in request for timeout

Tags: apache2, timeout, virtualhost, ping, http-status-code-403

I have apache2 setup with several virtual hosts, but I have it setup so that if you visit the IP address in your browser you get an error 403. When I ping the domain name of one of my virtual hosts, it always just responds with request for timeout, never the latency, why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your hosting provider (or your Linux distro) has firewalled [`ICMP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) protocol which is necessary for `ping` to work correctly.

Note that Apache needs only [`TCP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) to work properly, and does not need `ICMP`, which is completely different protocol. In other words, `ping` may be completely firewalled, and yet, your website will respond correctly.

Some websites actively firewall `ICMP`, most notable example is `microsoft.com`.

Comment: The firewall on my VPS is set to drop by default, according to customer support the only way to allow pinging is to accept by default